Nuxt 3 & nuxt/apollo cant call mutate function if called from @click
When I am trying to call the mutate function with a button I get no response and the mutation is not working yet when I call it on page reload everything is working fine.
This is my login.vue
<template>
    <div class="h-screen flex items-center justify-center w-full">
        <form class="w-1/3" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <div class="p-5">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-5">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="input w-full"
                    v-model="formData.email"  />
            </div>
            <div class="p-5">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="input w-full"
                    v-model="formData.password"  />
            </div>
            <div class="p-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-violet-700" >Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {{ res }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const formData = ref({
    email: '',
    password: ''
})

const res = ref('')

const mutation = gql`
    mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!, $device_name: String! = "web") {
        login(email: $email, password: $password, device_name: $device_name) 
    }
`

const variables = ref({
    email: "wilke.jonas@gmx.de",
    password: "jonas0311"
})
const { mutate: login } = useMutation(mutation)

const onSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await login(variables.value)
    res.value = response?.data.login
}

// onSubmit()

</script>

<style scoped></style>

When onSubmit() is called as shown in the comment below the function everything is working fine

Any errors in the console? Anything in the network tab or any other devtools? Add a console.log in the onSubmit function to be sure that your function is reached.

Thanks, didnt look at the console. I got a CSRF mismatch. Dont know why it worked when I called the function on page reload, but now its working.
